# jQuery live search when 4 numbers entered

Tags: jquery, livesearch

How do I do a live search only once the user has typed in 4 numbers into the input?

It basically needs to contact the php page using $ajax which I already have.

I thought it might be an `input.length == 4` but I tried it and failed.

Comment: By "4 numbers" you mean 4 digits like "1234" or some kind of 4 numbers separated by spaces ("123 54123 523 5"), commas ("123,54123,523,5"), etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to check if the value of the input consists exactly of four digits.

```
$("#test").keyup(function() {
  if(/^\d{4}$/.test($(this).val())) {
    alert('please call $.ajax here');
  }
});
```

where `#test` is:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/elabaz/edit#javascript,live)** is the code.

Answer (score 0):

try `$('#input').val().length;`

Comment: Remove that extra `)` :). I guess "4 numbers" in the question was little bit misleading for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a regex problem:

```
if ($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'').length >= 4) {
}
```

You should also prevent any keypress that doesn't pass this test:

```
/^[^0-9, ]$/.test($(this).val())
```